# Prompt Box Not Working

Tags: javascript

The 3 other buttons are functioning as they should, but the last one which is the one that enables one to input a specific color to change isn't working. I have tried and checked unless I'm really dense and cannot see what is wrong... Sorry in advance if I failed to see something so obvious.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>FA2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id=js>JavaScript</h1>
    <script>
    function show(){
       document.getElementById("js").innerHTML="is a Programming Language"}
    
    function reset(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
       document.getElementById("js").innerHTML="JavaScript"}
    
    function red(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"}
    
    function green(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"}
    
    function blue(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"}
      
    function type(){
       var color = prompt("Enter Color");
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color}
    </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
    body
    {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    <hr>
    
    Change Background:
    <button onclick="red()">Red</button>
    <button onclick="green()">Green</button>
    <button onclick="blue()">Blue</button>
    <button onclick="type()">Type Color</button>
    <hr>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The console in Chrome shows error:

> Uncaught TypeError: type is not a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting, it seems to be treating `type` as a reserved keyword or something, although I am sure it is not. Simply renaming the method to something else, like `typein()`, solves the problem:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>FA2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id=js>JavaScript</h1>
    <script>
    function show(){
       document.getElementById("js").innerHTML="is a Programming Language"}
    
    function reset(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
       document.getElementById("js").innerHTML="JavaScript"}
    
    function red(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"}
    
    function green(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"}
    
    function blue(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"}
      
    function typein(){
       var color = prompt("Enter Color");
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color}
    </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
    body
    {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    <hr>
    
    Change Background:
    <button onclick="red()">Red</button>
    <button onclick="green()">Green</button>
    <button onclick="blue()">Blue</button>
    <button onclick="typein()">Type Color</button>
    <hr>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## Some Explanation

Investigating further, the cause appears to be that the `onclick` function itself is run within the context of the `button` element and as there is a `type` property on this element `type` in this context is the string "submit". You can also do this for other properties, e.g. textContent to get the button text:

```html
<button onclick="console.log(type, textContent)">Some Text</button>
```

This makes some sort of sense but I don't understand how it happens - if the button was bound to the onclick function (e.g. using `bind()`), you would need to call `this.type` to get that property value. Maybe a JS guru can explain?

Comment: Weird.  Doing this directly on the console is fine: `function type() { alert('x'); } type();`

Comment: Ahh - `type` is an attribute on `button` - it's using that.  If you change it to `<button onclick="alert(type)">` it alerts the default, `"submit"`.

Answer (score 2):

While [Rhumborl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876179/791010) explains a bit about what is going on and how to work around it, I'd like to show what the specification actually says, and why you can't use `type` in an inline event handler in this way.

The specification [lists how to get](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler) the the current value of the event handler, going through a number of steps.  One of these is setting the Lexical Environment Scope thusly:

> If element is not null, let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope)

In our case, element is not null, so it's effectively being used as the scope of the function.  That means that any use of variables not explicitly declared will start by looking for properties on the element before falling back to higher level scopes (which is where the `type()` function is actually declared).

In addition to this, the [`<button>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) has a `type` property specified on it's IDL interface, defined as:

> The type IDL attribute must reflect the content attribute of the same name, limited to only known values.

So when executing:

```
<button onclick="type()">
```

It will first find the `type` property on the button, which must match the attribute as above.  The `type` attribute defaults to `"submit"`, so it's effectively trying to run `"submit"()`.  Clearly this isn't a function, and that's why you see:

> type is not a function

Ideally you wouldn't use inline event handlers in this way, and instead bind an event handler to the click event elsewhere using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (or a library like jQuery etc), but that's getting beyond the scope of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name from Type to anything. Try below example.

```
function getType(){
   var color = prompt("Enter Color");
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = color}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
}

</style>

<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<hr>

Change Background:
<button onclick="red()">Red</button>
<button onclick="green()">Green</button>
<button onclick="blue()">Blue</button>
<button onclick="getType()">Type Color</button>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you to you as well :D